# Question about proof of Lemma 6.13 on Lee's Smooth Manifolds: projection map $\pi_v:\mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ with kernel $\mathbb{R}v$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I am having difficulty understanding the proof below from John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds.

First, what exactly is the projection map $\pi_v$? I can't see how a projection map can be defined by having the kernel $\mathbb{R}v$.

Finally, the correction on the book states that this argument does not apply when $M$ has nonempty boundary because in that case $M\times M$ is not a smooth manifold with boundary. But we can consider the restrictions to $\kappa$ to $(M\times Int M)\setminus \Delta_m$ and to $(M \times \partial M)\setminus \Delta_M$ (both of which are smooth manifolds with boundary), and note that there is a point $[v]\in \mathbb{RP}^{N-1}$ that is not in the image of $\tau $ or either of these restrictions of $\kappa$.

How do we know that there is such a point $[v]\in \mathbb{RP}^{N-1}$? And why are $(M\times Int M)\setminus \Delta_M$ and $(M \times \partial M)\setminus \Delta_M$ and $TM \setminus M_0$ smooth manifolds with boundary? I know each of $M\times Int M$, $M \times \partial M$ and $TM$ are but how do we ensure they are still smooth manifolds with boundary minus $\Delta_M$ and $M_0$? Is it simply because they become open subsets?

[image]

Comment: The projection is on the hyperplane $v^{\perp}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n | \ x\cdot v=0\}$

Comment: @MatteoIaccarino thank you but why is this projection map a bounded linear map?

Comment: As an example of the projection in lower dimensions, if $v = e_3$ in $\mathbb R^3$ (the third standard basis vector), the projection $\pi_{e_3}(x,y,z) = (x,y)$ is a projection with kernel $\mathbb Re_3$. In other words, $\pi_v$ is orthogonal projection onto the linear subspace $v^\perp$, which makes it a linear map. We are in finite dimensions, so every linear map is bounded.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz So $\pi_v(x)=x-cv$ for some $c\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @AlexOrtiz Could you help me with my second question? Why is there such a $[v]$ that is not in the image of $\tau$ or restrictions of $\kappa$?

Comment: The map you propose is not a linear map. You can define $\pi_v$ by choosing coordinates for $\mathbb R^N$ of the form $x = x_v v + x'$, where $x'\in v^\perp$. Then $\pi_v(x) = x'$.